# styling for all elements except for a div and all divs inside it

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$('#main div').not('#2 > #3').each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

  <div id="1">
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>
  <div id="2">
    <div id="3">Some text in paragraph 2</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>
  <div id="3">
    <div>Some text in paragraph 3</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>

</div>
```

I want the css not to be applied for the nested divs of div with `id=2`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You have to exclude div#2 in this way:

```
$('#main > div').not('#2').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Or more simply:

```
$('#main > div').not('#2').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Pure CSS:

```
#main > div:not(#2) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**A)** if your mean be `#3` only:

> default value for `background-color` is `transparent`. you do not set `background-color` for `#3` for this reason it get `transparent`(in this case, you see `blue` color,because `#2` have `background-color:blue`).

your selector is correct just insert initial value for `div`s:

```
div {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WUzNs/38/)

**B)** If your mean be `#2` and his childrens:

- Do not start the ID with the number(I change `#2` to `#a2`)

**Use this:**

```
#main>div:not(#a2) {
    background-color: blue!important;
}
```

```css
#main>div:not(#a2) {
  background-color: blue!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="1">
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>
  <div id="a2">
    <div id="3">Some text in paragraph 2</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>
  <div id="3">
    <div>Some text in paragraph 3</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#main>div').not('#2').each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

  <div id="1">
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>
  <div id="2">
    <div id="3">Some text in paragraph 2</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>
  <div id="3">
    <div>Some text in paragraph 3</div>
    <div>Some text in paragraph 1</div>
  </div><br>

</div>
```